# jQuery on Bootstrap 4 modal videos - make code DRY

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, dry

I have several videos on one page. They're all in Bootstrap 4 modals, so I had to find some code that makes autoplay-after-modal-is-shown for each and every video work. (If I was selecting all videos at once, they would all play and pause at once.) 
As a result, I have produced some pretty WET code.

I would like to make this DRY:

```
// Makes video1 play after modal is shown and pause video when the modal is closed
$('#video1').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
  $('#autoplay-video1')[0].play();
})
$('#video1').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
  $('#autoplay-video1')[0].pause();
})

// video 2
$('#video2').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
  $('#autoplay-video2')[0].play();
})
$('#video2').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
  $('#autoplay-video2')[0].pause();
})

// video 3
$('#video3').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
  $('#autoplay-video3')[0].play();
})
$('#video3').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
  $('#autoplay-video3')[0].pause();
})

// video 4 ... (etc.)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the "begin with" selector may work for you:

```js
$('[id^=video]').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
  $('#autoplay-' + $(this).attr('id'))[0].play();
})
$('[id^=video]').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
  $('#autoplay-' + $(this).attr('id'))[0].pause();
})
```

But this could break if you've got other elements with an id starting with "video", like this:

```html
<div id="video-wrapper">…</div>
```

Therefore I'd recommend to use a custom data attribute to avoid these problems:

```html
<video data-video="1">…</video>
```

```js
$('[data-video]').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
  $('#autoplay-video' + $(this).attr('data-video'))[0].play();
})
$('[data-video]').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
  $('#autoplay-video' + $(this).attr('data-video'))[0].pause();
})
```

Comment: I've tried both of your suggestions, even though I didn't have any other elements with an ID of "video" (I just made my unique video IDs more neutral-sounding so I don't confuse anyone with weird names). I prefer classes over IDs.

With your dry solutions the autoplay isn't working for me anymore.

Would you tell me what kind of HTML markup you'd be using? 

Here's my HTML, jQ  + your second solution: 
[link](https://codepen.io/dianaheit/pen/WNNYzXb) 

and how would I avoid giving the same ID to all of my videos? I would use a class instead.

Comment: Set `data-video="1"` on the modal, not on the video. And then use `<video id="autoplay-video1" …>` to let my code sample to the link between the modal and the video.

Comment: But if you've got a single video per modal, there's something even simpler, like this: `$('.modal-vide').on('shown.bs.modal', function() { $(this).find('video')[0].play(); })`. Just add a `modal-video` on your modals, and search for the first video tag inside it.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried all kinds of combinations. None of this works for me.